# PCRE - RegEx: Match between nth words

Tags: regex, pcre

I’m processing emails from Outlook that are HTML formatted using Nintex. The problem that is occurring is the email has an extra information that is skewing my regex.

What I need to do is capture the email body that does not have the HTML formatting. I have identified a common word that is used for the start and end of the email bodies. The problem is this word also appears in the HTML formatted email as well as in the beginning.

```
Simple Mail Transfer Protocol Information, keywords some other data Keyword

KEYWORD
Non HTML formatted email that I want to capture
KEYWORD

KEYWORD
HTML formatted email that I do not want to capture.
KEYWORD
```

I need to capture the non HTML version of the email between `KEYWORD`

```
Keyword
Non HTML formatted email that I want to capture
Keyword
```

Comment: [Nintex uses .NET regex](http://help.nintex.com/en-US/O365/O365WorkFlow/Workflow%20Actions%20-%20STD/Regular%20Expression.htm), why tag PCRE?

Comment: On the other hand, if you need *something like* [`Keyword(?!\s+Keyword)([^<>]*?)Keyword`](https://regex101.com/r/mZ0dE6/1), it can be used with .NET and PCRE.

Comment: Your answer is working. However it is capturing I need it to be check the case

Comment: *check the case*?  [Matching?](https://regex101.com/r/mZ0dE6/2)

Comment: Why not `(?m)^(?<=Keyword\n).+(?=\nKeyword)`? (or with `\r\n` in place of `\n`.)

Comment: Wiktor can you post your answer please so I can mark it correct